# How to remove repeated add log from table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, duplicates

I have a log table where multiple rows have been included with ADD status ("`status = 0`" means "add").

How to remove `status = 0` but it must be unrepeated value. For example each transaction id (tid) must have only one value with `status = 0`.

For example;

```
id tid       tblname           type     status 
1   101     x                   U              0
2   101     x                   U              0
3   102     x                   U              0
4   102     x                   U              0
5   102     x                   U              0
```

Must return:

```
id  tid     tblname       type           status 
1   101     x            U              0
3   102     x            U              0
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11130964/delete-duplicate-rows-in-sql-server-2010

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parameterizing an SQL IN clause?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-an-sql-in-clause)

Comment: Sorry, i understood  mistake. sorry.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove duplicate rows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a cte and `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH x AS (SELECT rn = Row_number() 
                       OVER( 
                         partition BY tid 
                         ORDER BY id) 
         FROM   dbo.log
         WHERE  status = 0 
                AND tblname = 'X' 
                AND type = 'U') 
DELETE FROM  x 
WHERE  rn > 1
```